# Cannot resolve symbol v7 : import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to import this :
`import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`

But I got that : "Cannot resolve symbole v7".

Indeed, when I'm typing `android.support.` I can choose v4 but not v7

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bibstandardandroidstudio"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to follow this tutorial : [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

I saw that `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` should unlock my situation but it don't seem to work

Comment: try to rebuild project.

Comment: I did it and it still does not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following dependency to use recylerview:

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

or for Android X:

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'`

as specified in point 2 under "Add the support library" [creating recylerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).
 You can use the recyclerview under androidx like so:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I already added : `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'` to my build.gradle, but it don't seem to work...
Is `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'` working like v7.widget.recyclerview ?

Comment: @lain I got an error while running my app.
It seems like that is due to : `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`
Error :      
`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList`

Comment: you're missing the `x` after android: `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works. But you know, you cannot see my "+1" because I don't have enough reputation. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

The support library has got a new version and is no longer used. I also recommend to use AndroidX.

Click Refactor option in the android studio ribbon and choose Migrate to AndroidX. If you are new there then first create a copy of the project and then try AndroidX. Well, there is not much difference.

Then use the AndroidX recyclerview:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```